# in chrome browser (or any browser), when you select a word and then use the arrow keys to move the cursor, how is that done within the browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, javascript, cursor, text-cursor

I am trying to understand how the cursor works within web browser and how the arrow keys move the cursor and the highlighted text (as I see on most websites it changes line accurately most of the time).

I am mainly interested in seeing is there an api that I can use with browser extensions, or failing that client-side javascript.

Comment: Just a comment, but I believe this is a function of the OS, etc (at least if you're talking about Shift + Arrow Keys). If I am not misunderstanding your description, you can get the same results in e.g. Notepad. This likely has nothing to do with the browser itself.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes more sense!